# Android create a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm new in Android and have a question.

**How could I create a TextView in my MainActivity. How could I do this?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean programmatically? you need to learn layout inflater.inflate

Comment: What have you tried so far? And please use appropriate formatting for your question.

Comment: It's so simple as `TextView textView = new TextView(this);`

Comment: Please care about your rep: points and should make question to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a TextView in Java like this:**

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText("This is a text");
parentView.addView(tv);
```

**Create a TextView in XML like this:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selected_iconpack_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No Icon Pack Selected"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

In your layout file add a TextView object like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

in your Java file do this:

Declare a variable of type TextView and link it to the TextView in your layout

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```